# Scrabble vs. Unspeakable Words

Tags: scrabble, scoring, unspeakable-words

What are the differences between the letter distribution and the letter scoring on Scrabble and Unspeakable Words?

Are there any other differences?
Are these games similar in some ways?

<sub><sub>[Next question >](http://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/51060/)</sub></sub>

Answer (score 2):

The letter distribution has similarities. However, Scrabble allows you to re-use previously played tiles, so these numbers below don't represent the true availability of letters. Also, there doesn't appear to be any wild card in Unspoken Words (a role filled by the blank tile in Scrabble).

The point distribution is quite different. Furthermore, Unspoken Words has other major differences in scoring (e.g. the lack of Scrabble's letter and word multipliers).

```
          Number of Cards or Tiles       Points per Card or Tile
          ----------------------------   ----------------------------
          UW:C      UW:D      Scrabble   UW:C      UW:D      Scrabble
--------  --------  --------  --------   --------  --------  --------
A               10        11         9         5         5         1
B                2         4         2         5         5         3
C                2         5         2         0         0         3
D                3         6         4         2         2         2
E               10        11        12         4         4         1
F                2         4         2         3         3         4
G                2         4         3         2         2         2

H                3         5         2         4         4         4
I                9        10         9         4         4         1
J                1         3         1         2         2         8
K                1         3         1         3         3         5
L                5         7         4         1         1         1
M                3         5         2         3         3         3
N                5         7         6         2         2         1

O                8        10         8         0         0         1
P                2         4         2         3         3         3
Q                1         1         1         2         4         0
R                5         7         6         4         4         1
S                5         8         4         0         0         1
T                5         8         6         2         2         1
U                4         7         4         0         0         1

V                2         3         2         1         1         4
W                2         4         2         3         3         4
X                1         2         1         4         4         8
Y                2         5         2         3         3         4
Z                1         2         1         2         2         0
Wild             -         -         2         -         -         0
```

(Internationalized versions of Scrabble have different letter and point distributions.)

These games are obviously similar in some way: They are both word construction games. That said, the lack of word reuse in Unspoken Words and the scoring differences should make the games rather different. (I've never played either version of Unspoken Words.)

---

Sources:

- [Rules for Unspoken Words: Classic Edition](https://www.playroomentertainment.com/pub/media/wysiwyg/game-instruction/unspeakable-words-classic-edition.pdf)
- [Rules for Unspoken Words: Deluxe Edition](https://www.playroomentertainment.com/pub/media/wysiwyg/game-instruction/unspeakable-words-deluxe-edition.pdf)
- [Rules for Scrabble](https://scrabble.hasbro.com/en-us/rules)
- [FAQ about Scrabble](https://scrabble.hasbro.com/en-us/faq)

Comment: "Z" in Scrabble scores 10 points, not 0. Also "Q"